# Read and Write strings via ByteBuf using byte[] array

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to send a string through netty with a ByteBuf.
First of all I convert the string to a byte array like that:

```
byteBuf.writeInt(this.serverName.length());
byteBuf.writeInt(this.ipAdress.length());

byteBuf.writeBytes(this.serverName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byteBuf.writeBytes(this.ipAdress.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

This works well, but I don't know how to read the bytes to convert them back to the string?

I tried something like that:

```
int snLen = byteBuf.readInt();
int ipLen = byteBuf.readInt();

byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuf.readableBytes()];

System.out.println(byteBuf.readBytes(bytes).readByte());
this.ipAdress = "";
```

There must be something to get the bytes back. You can send bytes from a string but can't get the bytes back at the end? Seems like there is a method for that, but I don't have an idea how to do that.

I hope anyone from you can help me.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @tima `io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf.class != java.nio.ByteBuffer.class`

Comment: @Ferrybig I see now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In netty 4.1 you can use:

```
byteBuf.writeCharSequence(...)
byteBuf.readCharSequence(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect :)

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if it included a complete example, rather than "..." where the important bits go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an untested answer:

I assume the data order is correct.

Use this, method "readBytes(ByteBuf dst, int length)" : [readBytes](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/ByteBuf.html#readBytes-io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf-int-)

Transmit side change to:

```
byteBuf.writeInt(this.serverName.getBytes().length);
byteBuf.writeInt(this.ipAdress.getBytes().length);
```

Receiving side:

```
int snLen = byteBuf.readInt();
int ipLen = byteBuf.readInt();

byte[] bytesServerName = new byte[snLen];
byte[] bytesIp = new byte[ipLen];

byteBuf.readBytes(bytesServerName,snLen);
byteBuf.readBytes(bytesIp, ipLen);

String serverName  = new String(bytesServerName); 
String ipAddress   = new String(bytesIp);   

System.out.println(bytesServerName);
System.out.println(bytesIp);
```

Comment: He is writing the `.length` (length in chars) of the string, this isn't the same as the length in bytes, also, you never initiated the `bytesServerName` and the `bytesIp` variables

Comment: Thanks, fixed those.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Netty's own StringEncoder and StringDecoder ? http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringEncoder.html